# onclick event is not working clicking same element again IOS and Android

Tags: javascript, android, html, ios

Android and iOS browsers handle the click event differently.

Say for example, an onclick event handler is attached to an element.  When it is clicked for the first time it works fine, but when the same element is clicked again, it's not working. If we click some other element and then click on the previous element it works.

Is there any workaround to solve this issue so that if the same element is clicked again will work perfectly ??

Comment: Post your code. No one can solve your problem without seeing what you doing wrong.

Comment: I didn't such situation with click in mobile platforms. Also, I usually use `hammer.js`

Comment: Please post some code to understand the context. Are you attaching/detaching events dynamically ?

Answer (score 0):

The question is not clear. Please post some code to explain the problem.

For android if you are talking about onclick in a webview then you should check if you have enabled Javascript.

```
webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
```

Apologies for posting this as answer as I don't have 50 rep points for commenting.